# Retaining study participants in a longitudinal research study

Tags: experimental-psychology

Which methods can be followed to retain participants in a longitudinal research study?

We tried to retain participants by sending reminder messages, and also a bonus at the second time point, but none of these two methods worked so far. Only half of the participants came back to take part in the second time point. It hampers the counterbalancing of different variables. Would you please share your experiences to retain the participants?